# Pointer returning garbage value

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know what I'm doing wrong I'm stuck on this for the past two hours. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My code is the following:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* findLargest(int* arr,int size){
    return &arr[size-1];
}

int main(){

    int size=3;
    int arr[3]={3,4,5};

    int* largest=&arr[size-1];
    int* largest2=malloc(100);
    largest2=findLargest(*arr,size);
    printf("%d",largest);
    printf("%d",*largest2);
}
```

I get a garbage value when I execute.

Comment: Read the warnings and errors when you compile.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.

Comment: I just didn't have a \n between the two printfs and the first was returning a garbage value which it should because it is a pointer

Comment: Always check compiler warnings. `findlargest.c:16:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘findLargest’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: `int* largest2=malloc(100);
    largest2=findLargest(*arr,size);` --> `int *largest2=findLargest(arr, size);`, `printf("%d",largest);` --> `printf("%d\n", *largest);`

Comment: i agree.. the compiler did warn me

Comment: more importantly .. i had to fix this line .. largest2=findLargest(arr,size); instead of largest2=findLargest(*arr,size);

Comment: Also Need `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

Only pass `arr` to findLargest, this is already a pointer

```
largest2=findLargest(arr,size);
```

printf contents of largest, not the pointer itself

```
printf("%d\n", *largest);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you have the line:

```
int* largest2=malloc(100);
```

The malloc'd pointer is immediately lost in the next line when you assign to largest2 again.

I would also consider assigning `size` like so:

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

This is safer if you change the contents of `arr` in the future.

With all these changes main looks like:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[3]={3,4,5};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int* largest=&arr[size-1];
    int* largest2=findLargest(arr,size); // Only pass array to findLargest, this is already a pointer
    printf("%d\n", *largest); // printf contents of largest, not the pointer
    printf("%d\n", *largest2);
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The `sizeof`-*operator* evaluates to a `size_t`, not to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is this line

```
printf("%d",largest);
```

Where you're not de-referencing the pointer. Nor is there a space or new line after the value causing more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you can't edit address of pointer, you've to edit value of pointer
like this:

```
int * v = malloc(sizeof(int)); //WRONG
int n=54;
v=&n;

int * v = malloc(sizeof(int)); //CORRECT
int n=54;
*v=n;
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, the problem was simple. Just in case someone runs into this confusion this can help.

The correct code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* findLargest(int* arr,int size){
    return &arr[size-1];
}

int main(){

    int size=3;
    int arr[3]={3,4,5};

    int* largest=&arr[size-1];
    int* largest2=malloc(100);
    largest2=findLargest(arr,size);//Not findLargest(*arr,size)
    printf("%d",*largest2);
}
```

Comment: This occurs memory leak.

Comment: Well in your new code then, the "largest" variable is useless. Also what @BLUEPIXY said. Use free(largest2) to release the pointer.